# how to insert php code inside javascript code

Tags: php, jquery

I need to store the content of `story` inside mysql table.

This content will later be normally loaded on another page using `php`.

`piano.php` is a third, separate file and I don't want it on the current page, but only on the target page.

So I'm trying to insert php code inside `story` content but it is automatically commented (see in console);

How to do this?

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var a = "<div class='part partpiano'><?php include('piano.php');?></div>";
  $(a).insertBefore($('.title'));
  console.log($('.story').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='story'>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div><br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: `php` is server side language,`javascript` is client side language,how can you manipulate server side via client side?

Comment: why dont you use ajax

Comment: You could use ajax or jquery `load('file.php)`;

Comment: @TarangP, I'm using ajax, of course, but I firstly need the propper content as a variable

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, using `load` on target page will make page loading slow.

Comment: @lucumt, pls read my post carefully

Comment: @puerto Wish you can find the answer

Comment: You're adding HTML to the page _**after**_ PHP has finished executing.  PHP runs on the server, creates HTML and then sends it to the browser.  If you try to add PHP to the page at that point then _**it is running in your browser - NOT your web server**_, so PHP commands do not work.  You can add the element to the page and then use `$(".part.partpiano").load("piano.php");` to ask your web server to parse the PHP file and return the results (HTML).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Comment: @EriksKlotins OP mentions storing something in a database, but the question **is not** about posting a form.  Please read the whole question and look at the code to see what OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: @Archer, of course, I said want to store the code inside a table, and not to execute on the current page.

Comment: In that case your question makes no sense.

Comment: It's really a question of what type of file you are using. Is it a .php file? Go ahead! Drop some php in the middle of that JS! Is it a .js file? It won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a much better practice to avoid mixing PHP with JavaScript. PHP is a **server-side** language and as a result, executes differently from the browser. It *can* work but usually leads to unexpected behaviour and for the most part, it's much cleaner to keep everything separate.

You can achieve passing data between PHP and JS using hidden inputs or DOM elements with data-* attributes, e.g.

```
<div id="php-data" data-id="<?php echo $foo; ?>"></div>
```

then in your jQuery

```
let id = $('#php-data').attr('data-id');
```

However, for your problem in particular (as it's an include). It's much **much** better to simply include the file on load using a class of hidden:

css:

```
.hidden {
    display: none
}
```

html/php:

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="part partpiano hidden">
        <?php include_once 'piano.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$('button').click(function()
{
    $('.part').removeClass('hidden')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include PHP in your page in the way you've tried, as you've found.  PHP is executed on the server and the results are returned to your browser, so if you add PHP with Javascript then it's not executed/parsed and is just added as text (your browser cannot execute PHP).

What you can do is add the container element to the page and then load the contents afterwards, like this...

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var a = "<div class='part partpiano'>Loading...</div>";
  $(a).insertBefore($('.title'));
  $(a).load("piano.php");
});
```

Comment: ah, forgot about .load() ... #JSScrub

Comment: Aren't you assuming that he is trying to include php in a javascript file? I think he is trying to include javascript in a php file... which is entirely possible

Comment: @Weft I've read the code - if it's an incorrect assumption then the OP can tell me, but to me no, it does not look vaguely like they're trying to store javascript in a PHP file.  This is very a common mistake that people make.

Comment: @Weft that's not what OP is doing, they're including this HTML snippet `<div class="part partpiano"><?php include('piano.php'); ?></div>` and then attempt to insert it before `.title` - there is no desire to use JS in PHP but to use PHP in JS - which won't work.

Comment: @Weft - we disagree.  Discuss this with the OP, not me.  Okay?

Comment: @Archer, pls point the part of my post where you saw I want include js inside php?

Comment: @puerto Archer doesn't **weft** does - please follow comment thread closely